# REST method GET for searching by criteria as json fro mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I have an nodejs server with express and mongoose and I'd like to use method GET for search accoring to criteria which I'd like to provide as JSON object does anyone can help me how to implement it?

Or maybe should I use POST or PUT to make it?

Comment: So, is it GET, PUT or POST you want?

Comment: For me POST - use to add new object PUT use to update GET use to get that is how I understand it but I'm not sure that in GET I can provide json query as body etc.

Comment: @Robert you can't provide json query, but you can provide search query. E.g `http://hostname.com/modelname?field=2&another_param=3` and handle it in your express router

Comment: @AndrewVolchenko are you able to provide me any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://hostname/modelname?criteria1=1&criteria2=2`

```
router.route('/modelname')
    .get(function (req, res, next) {
        req.query.criteria1 === 1 // true
        req.query.criteria2 === 2 // true
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure of what HTTP VERB you'd want to use,

```
POST - is primarily used for creating resources on the server

PUT - is used to update an existing resource

GET- to retrieve a resource
```

I would use GET in this case

```
GET http://myhost.com?q=word1+word2+word3+word4

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
   // do something with the req.query.q array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options - using HTTP GET params or encoding whole criteria as JSON string and passing that string.

First option, by using params:

```
?crit[foo.bar][$eq]=abc&crit[foo.baz][$ne]=def
```

You can read it in nodejs/express via `req.query.crit`. But this is bad idea because there's no way of retaining data types. For example number `1` becomes string `"1"`. Don't use it - MongoDB is data type sensitive so query `{"foo.bar":{$eq:1}}` is completely different from `{"foo.bar":{$eq:"1"}}`

Second option is to urlencode JSON criteria:

```
?critJSON=%7B%22foo.bar%22%3A%7B%22%24eq%22%3A%20%22abc%22%7D%2C%22foo.baz%22%3A%7B%22%24ne%22%3A%20%22def%22%7D%7D
```

And parse it on nodejs/express side:

```
var crit = JSON.parse(req.query.critJSON)
```

This way your data types are retained and it will work as expected.